# Proving that two specific sets have equal cardinality in Isabelle

Tags: set, isabelle, cardinality

I´m having trouble proving that two sets have the same cardinality.
All the following sets are finite.

First let´s assume we have set (M::b set) and a function foo :: "b set ⇒ b set ⇒ bool"
such that (foo A C = foo B C ⟷ A = B) and for every A in M there is in fact a C, such that foo A C.

I´m trying to show that card {S. ∃A∈M. (S = {C. foo A C}) } = card M. 
The informal proof for this is obvious, but I can´t seem to find an efficient proof
in Isabelle; neither for the ≤ nor the ≥ part.

Answer (score 4):

Okay so the first step is that you should write this set comprehension `{S. ∃A∈M. (S = {C. foo A C}) }` in a more convenient way. A first step would be `{{C. foo A C} |A. A ∈ M}`, but I would suggest using the ‘set image’ operator:

```
lemma "{S. ∃A∈M. (S = {C. foo A C})} = (λA. {C. foo A C}) ` M" by blast
```

Then you can simply use the fact that `(λA. {C. foo A C})` is injective and the rule `card_image`, which says that the cardinality of the image of a set under an injective function is the same as that of the original set:

```
lemma
  assumes "⋀A B C. A ∈ M ⟹ B ∈ M ⟹ foo A C = foo B C ⟷ A = B"
  shows   "card {S. ∃A∈M. (S = {C. foo A C})} = card M"
proof -
  have "{S. ∃A∈M. (S = {C. foo A C})} = (λA. {C. foo A C}) ` M"
    by blast
  also have "inj_on (λA. {C. foo A C}) M"
    using assms by (auto simp: inj_on_def)
  hence "card ((λA. {C. foo A C}) ` M) = card M"
    by (rule card_image)
  finally show ?thesis .
qed
```